# how to generate thumnail of my site's home page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

how could i dynamically generate few thumbnail of my site's home page and shows them in another page. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be done using [WebBrowser control in .NET framework 2.0](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Get-Web-Site-Thumbnail-Image.aspx)

here are some other links

[Build A Self-Caching ASP.NET Web Site Thumbnail Control](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/b7cce396-e2b3-42d7-9571-cdc4eb38f3c1/build-a-selfcaching-asp.aspx)

[Creating Website Thumbnails in ASP.NET](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/graphics/creating-website-thumbnails-in-asp-net)

or a third party web service like [WebShots](http://www.webshotspro.com/) or [thumbalizr](http://www.thumbalizr.com/)